# A function which acts differently depending on the last keystroke

Tags: elisp, keystrokes

I would like to define a function which behaves differently depending on the last keystroke. More specifically I would like that it behaves differently if the last keystroke (**before the execution of that function**) has been `<home>`. Like below

```
(defun foo ()
  (interactive)
  (if (the-last-keystroke-is-home)
     (message "yes")
    (message "no")))
```

Comment: Why not re-bind <home> and do your thing there?

Comment: Is it the key that really matters, or the command? If it's the command, `last-command` is probably what you want. If it's the key, look at [key-chord.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KeyChord).

Comment: @Gilles for my case, the key matters, thanks for mentioning key-chord. I will look at.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could take advantage of the [`recent-keys`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Recording-Input.html) function. It returns a vector of the last 300 events.

Using

```lisp
(defun get-last-key ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((vect (recent-keys)))
    (aref vect (1- (length vect)))))
```

And then doing <kbd>C-x C-e</kbd> on

```
(get-last-key)
```

You will get

```
5 (#o5, #x5, ?\C-e)
```

You will "just" have to compare this to the keystroke you want.

Note that as suggested by @stsquad, when you will call this function, your last keystroke probably won't be `<home>` (more likely `<return>`). So depending on what you want to achieve, re-binding `<home>` might be the way to go.

---

If you want a "readable" key, use the `single-key-description` function. To be thorough, you should also use `prin1-to-string`:

```
(defun get-last-key ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((vect (recent-keys))
        (key (aref vect (1- (length vect)))))
        (if (or (integerp key) (symbolp key) (listp key))
            (single-key-description key)
            (prin1-to-string key nil)))
        )

(get-last-key); C-xC-e will give the string "C-e"
```

Comment: Regardless of the previous keystrokes,doing `C-x C-e` on `(get-last-key)` gives only 5.  Also the value of `(if (equal (get-last-key) "home")` is always nil. I think I misunderstand something here.

Comment: Use `single-key-description` then. You will have to compare to `"<home>"`

Comment: `last-command-event` might be useful. A few other related functions and variables are : `this-command-keys`, `this-single-command-keys`, `this-command-keys-vector`, `this-single-command-raw-keys` and possibly `current-prefix-arg`.

Comment: Thanks now if I in my original function I put `(defun foo () (interactive) (if (equal get-last-key "<home>") (message "yes") (message "no")))`, then if I make <home> then running foo,  I expect that the message "yes" to be printed, but it prints "no". I think it is because of the line `(aref vect (1- (length vect))` in your code. I seems that it get the last entry of the recent-keys vector, but it should take the entry before the last entry.

Comment: Depending on the keystroke changing `(aref vect (1- (length vect)))` to `(aref vect (- (length vect) n))` where n is a convenient number can do the job.

Answer (score 3):

```el
(defun foo (keys)
  (interactive "kUse a key sequence: ")
  (let ((ks  (this-single-command-keys)))
    (setq ks  (aref ks (1- (length ks))))
    (if (eq 'home ks) (message "yes") (message "no"))))
```

Get rid of the argument and the `interactive` spec, if you intend to use this in a context where a key sequence has already been read and you want to test it.

Wrt other attempts shown here so far: Don't test key *descriptions* (strings). Test the actual key/event values.